# Silent param not working for Update item field values

Tags: podio

I'm using version 0.7.9 of the java client library for the Podio API.  When sending a value of the **true** for the *silent* param, the item update is still displayed in the item's activity stream.

```
updateItemValues(item.getId(), valuesUpdates, bSilent, bHook)
```

According to the [API documentation](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/update-item-field-values-22367) that should not be the case.

```
If set to true, the object will not be bumped up in the stream 
and notifications will not be generated. 
Default value: false
```

**Question**: Is there a way to update an item via the Podio API so that the change is not displayed in the item's activity stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Item's activity stream is the only place where all item's changes are shown and only place where you can see who changed what and when and revert those changes. So, no, there is no way to hide this.

`Silent` parameter works well. There are number of other places where item's changes are shown: notifications, workspace activity stream, home activity stream. And `silent` parameter is silencing those changes as designed.